# Calculate integral of $ \iint\limits_D\frac{\cos x}{\cos x+\cos y}\,dA$, where D is region $x^2+y^2\leq1$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate 
$$ \iint\limits_D\frac{\cos x}{\cos x+\cos y}\,dA$$ where D is region $x^2+y^2\leq1$

Please give me how to compute this integral?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** Show that 
$$\iint\limits_D\frac{\cos x}{\cos x+\cos y}\,dA =\iint\limits_D\frac{\cos y}{\cos x+\cos y}\,dA$$

What is 
$$\iint\limits_D\frac{\cos x}{\cos x+\cos y}\,dA+\iint\limits_D\frac{\cos y}{\cos x+\cos y}\,dA ?$$

Comment: No. It can't be so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By the $x$-$y$ symmetry of $D$,  the integral is the same as the integral of $\frac{\cos y}{\cos x+\cos y}$. Add the two integrals.